# How to register FluentNHibernate with Ninject?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, ninject, structuremap

I'm setting up an ASP.NET MVC4 application and I'm using Ninject as my DI container.

In a previous project I used **StructureMap** with the following setup in my registry:

```
For<IAutoPersistenceConfiguration>()
    .Use<Sql2008AutoPersistenceConfiguration>()
    .Ctor<string>("connectionString")
    .Is("SomeConnectionStringHere");
For<ISessionSource>()
    .Singleton()
    .Use(x => new SessionSource(x.GetInstance<IAutoPersistenceConfiguration>().Build()));
```

Now I try to a similar setup in **Ninject**.  My try so far is:

```
Bind<IAutoPersistenceConfiguration>()
    .To<Sql2008AutoPersistenceConfiguration>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", "SomeConnectionStringHere");
Bind<ISessionSource>()
    .ToMethod(x => new SessionSource(
    x.Kernel.Get<IAutoPersistenceConfiguration>().Build())).InSingletonScope();
```

When I run this I get an FluentConfigurationException:

> An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory.

The other classes are all the same; IAutoPersistenceConfiguration and Sql2008AutoPersistenceConfiguration are all the same as before.  The version of NHibernate and FluentNHibernate are the same as before as well.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: The inner exception turned out to be more useful; "A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my Ninject setup was correct.  The exception I got hid an inner exception that I did not look at initially (see my own comment to my question).  Once I saw the inner exception all I had to do was fix my connection string and everything worked.